# How to map webdav folder seamlessly in windows

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, windows-xp, webdav

I have a webdav folder (generated by java webdav server), which I can access via "My network places" on WinXp (after mapping).
I would like for the user to see it via "My Computer" as a system folder (or something similar). Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could map it to a drive, but I don't think you can map it to a folder.
I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve / mean by "system folder".